# Spring Boot saving new field in document

Tags: java, spring-boot

I will explain one by one what I want to achieve. I hosted app right now on Heroku so you can actually see how it works, I thought its easier to understand.

- First log in here https://trip-advisor-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm
  you can use username `admin` and passoword `admin123`
- After that click on `AdventureHoliday` box and than `SummerCamps`.
- That is a random element from document (right now I dont have images in database for heroku) and there is a button randomize again. When page says `No more docs` just refresh page and you will have again two elements. (Right now its just two of them).

What I want to achieve?

You see there is a save button. So if user gets `Kieve Summer Camp` and click on save button, program should save that title and id of that element in User document in some list maybe in Mongo.

How I can achieve that?

How I can get a current element ID and that save that element in User element?

You can check my repo here https://github.com/jankovicdev/TripAdvisorApp

This is my service so far:

```
   public void saveDocument(String userId, String holidayId) {

    User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null);
    AdventureHolidays adventureHolidays = adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(holidayId).orElse(null);
    assert user != null;
    user.getAdventureHolidaysList().add(adventureHolidays);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

And controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/saveHoliday/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> saveLink(@PathVariable("id") String id, String holidayId) {
    userService.saveDocument(id, holidayId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But that doesnt work at all

Answer (score 0):

first take a form to use the save button to send the id and you have taken wrong type in button it should be type="submit" in file randomSummerCamps.html.